# Use of Woke up or wake up in present tense

Tags: present-tense

My friend called me early in the morning to get ready to leave for picnic.

I replayed him

"We are already woke up and doing packing."

Is the use of *We are already woke up* is correct?

Comment: We are already awake and packing.

Comment: Too complex to say what you want. "We woke up and are (now) packing." *woke up* is a completed action so you don't need *already*.

Comment: Can *woke up* be status of completed action like we are done. We

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct and neither is the second part "doing packing".  It should read either,

"We are already **awake** and **[are]** packing." (adjective)

or

"We have already **woken up** and **[have] started** packing." (past participle)

or

"We have already **woken up** and **are now** packing." (past participle and present continuous with emphasis using "now")